# Storing values in Selenium IDE with a non standard tag

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I have a non standard tag in an HTML doc that I need to write a selenium test for.

Here is the tag: `<evo:password>SomeText</evo:password>`

And my selenium ide command I'm trying:

```
Command: storeEval
Target: xpath=/x:html/x:body/x:div/x:div[1]/x:div[2]/x:div/x:div/x:table/x:tbody/x:tr[2]/x:td[2]/x:strong/x:evo:password
Value: adminPass
```

Not sure what I need as my Target to get this to work and store the value between my tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to get creative with my selector. I ended up using a CSS selector and getting the last element with it.

```
css=strong:last
```

I'm sure you can also use `:nth-child` among other natural css selectors.